# DriveApp Times Out no matter what i call

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I've tried adding oauth scopes and resetting the permissions.
I can't seem to get any call to drive app to work from Google App Script.

```
function testx()
{
  
  var folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  Logger.log(folder.getName());
}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Try opening up another spreadsheet and the script editor and try it again.

Comment: The result I get in Stack Driver Logs is `Jul 4, 2020, 4:15:24 PM Info My Drive`

Answer (score 1):

When something fails that only Google can fix, a.k.a there is a service outage or platform bug, it's better to post an issue on the issue tracker. For details see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support/#bugs